# Web3.JS 1.2.6 reporting PastEvents but not new events

Tags: web3js, events

relevant code:

```
token.getPastEvents('Approval', {
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
}, function (error, events) { console.log("ETHEREUM past events " + JSON.stringify(events)); });

token.events.Approval({
    fromBlock: 0
}, function (error, event) { console.log("NEW ETHEREUM EVENT " + JSON.stringify(event)); })

token.events.allEvents({
        fromBlock: 0
}, function (error, event) { console.log("NEW ETHEREUM EVENT " + JSON.stringify(event)); })
```

First call works perfectly.  The latter two do not.

I've got to be missing something pretty simple/stupid here . . . . but I can't pick it out.  :-(

Comment: If the exact same code works correctly for you on previous versions, then you should probably report that as an issue on their GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Wow!  I figured it out (and it's a worthwhile thing to know)

contract.events requires a web socket connection & contract.getPastEvents does not

The fix was to change

```
const web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8545');
```

to

```
const web3 = new Web3('ws://localhost:8545');
```